# LightInject register generic with parameters?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, light-inject

I have Interface IRepository and Class Repository with parameter constructor which Implement IRepository. Both Class and Interface are generic. I want to pass this parameter while registering. The code is as follows:

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        public Task<int> InsertAsync(T entity);
    } 

   public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
   {
      public MobileServiceClient MobileService { get; set; }

      public Repository(MobileServiceClient mobileService)
      {
        MobileService = mobileService;
      }

    public async Task<int> InsertAsync(T entity)
    {
        var table = MobileService.GetSyncTable<T>();
        await table.InsertAsync(entity);
        return 1;
    }
  }
```

I did generic class registration like this

```
Container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

I am not finding way to pass parameter while registering.

Comment: What prevents you from registering `MobileServiceClient` as `Singleton`?

Comment: @Steven I am initializing `MobileServiceClient` in one .Net Standard Library(Xamarin Forms) where I am registering all the services. I want to pass this instance to my business logic library.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would the following call not solve the problem?: `Container.Register<MobileServiceClient>(_ => client, new PerContainerLifetime())`.

Comment: is there any way to register client while registering Repository(`Container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));`) as it initializes the property like this `public Repository(MobileServiceClient mobileService)
      {
        MobileService = mobileService;
      }`  in constructor?